# String splitting incorrectly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, split

I am trying to split a string based on the delimter `\$`. I have tried this unsuccessfully.

The code that I have is at https://js.do/sun21170/77657, which is also pasted below.

**Question**: What am I doing wrong in this example when splitting by `\$`?

```js
var trickyString = "sd sewq wee r r ttttt $300 rrtrt utu iwiwi \$500 kjgf ihj \$215 ghi"; 

//document.getElementById("div0").innerHTML = trickyString;

function splitString() {
    //Why is splitting by \$ not giving 3 elements but is instead giving 4 elements?
    var array1 = trickyString.split(/\$/);
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "<b>Length = " + array1.length + "</b>";
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML += "<br>" + array1[i];
    }

    var array2 = trickyString.split("$");
    document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "<b>Length = " + array2.length + "</b>";
    for (var j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML += "<br>" + array2[j];
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="splitString();return false;">Split a tricky string</button>

<h4>Tricky string</h4>
<div id="div0" style="color:green">sd sewq wee r r ttttt $300 rrtrt utu iwiwi \$500 kjgf ihj \$215 ghi</div>

<h4>Split using \$ as delimiter</h4>
<div id="div1" style="color:red"></div>

<h4>Split using $ as delimiter</h4>
<div id="div2"  style="color:blue"></div>
```

Comment: It seems to work - you get four items. What is your expected result?

Comment: I have 2 `\$` strings in the main string, so shouldn't splitting  based on `\$` result in 3 elements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is stemming from the fact that within your regex `/\$/`, the `\$` is being interpreted as requesting the `$` to be treated as a literal character.

The regex you should be using is `/\\\$/`. As seen on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pv4Kse/1)

```
\\ matches the character \ literally (case sensitive)
\$ matches the character $ literally (case sensitive)
```

[image]

You are also suffering a similar issue within your string, where you are putting `\$`, it's being treated as a request to literally use the character `$`. This can be seen if you do a `console.log(trickyString);`, you'll notice the `\` are not in the output. You'll need to double escape the quote marks:

```
const trickyString = "sd sewq wee r r ttttt $300 rrtrt utu iwiwi \\$500 kjgf ihj \\$215 ghi;"
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but still I get 1 element instead of 3.

Comment: Your input data is wrong. The string `"\$"` is actually resolved as `"$"` since it's interpreted as an escaped dollar sign.

Comment: @Psytronic, so just 1 backslash before $ is treated as an escape character even though escaping a $ is not required. That makes sense. After changing `trickyString` to include `\\$` in place of '\$` it works. Thanks.

Comment: Correct, JS will always treat a backslash as a request to escape a character. Though escaping the `$` is not required in your string, it *is* required within the regex, as the `$` has special meaning for the regex (end of the string, or alternatively the end of a line if your regex has the `m` flag set)

Comment: Your last comment was awesome since I was missing the point that `$` has a special meaning in regex expression. Its very clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that slashes have special meaning both in a JS String and in a RegEx.

There are two critical parts here:

```
var trickyString = "sd sewq wee r r ttttt $300 rrtrt utu iwiwi \$500 kjgf ihj \$215 ghi";
```

Should be:

```
var trickyString = "sd sewq wee r r ttttt $300 rrtrt utu iwiwi \\$500 kjgf ihj \\$215 ghi";
```

Because `\$` will be interpreted as an `$`.

And also:

```
var array1 = trickyString.split(/\$/);
```

Should be:

```
var array1 = trickyString.split(/\\\$/g);
```

Both because `\$` will be interpreted as `$`, therefore the first `\\`, and `$` has, itself, an special meaning, therefore the second `\$`.

This is the code I have used:

```
var trickyString = "sd sewq wee r r ttttt $300 rrtrt utu iwiwi \\$500 kjgf ihj \\$215 ghi"; 

//document.getElementById("div0").innerHTML = trickyString;

function splitString() {
    //Why is splitting by \$ not giving 3 elements but is instead giving 4 elements?
    var array1 = trickyString.split(/\\\$/g);
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "<b>Length = " + array1.length + "</b>";
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML += "<br>" + array1[i];
    }

    var array2 = trickyString.split("$");
    document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "<b>Length = " + array2.length + "</b>";
    for (var j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML += "<br>" + array2[j];
    }
}
```

And these are the results:

```
Tricky string
sd sewq wee r r ttttt $300 rrtrt utu iwiwi \$500 kjgf ihj \$215 ghi
Split using \$ as delimiter
Length = 3
sd sewq wee r r ttttt $300 rrtrt utu iwiwi
500 kjgf ihj
215 ghi
Split using $ as delimiter
Length = 4
sd sewq wee r r ttttt
300 rrtrt utu iwiwi \
500 kjgf ihj \
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it results in 1 string after splitting. It should result in 3 elements after splitting.

Comment: Worked okay when I tested. I'm posting the full code for reference.

Comment: Yes, it works now after changing `\$` to `\\$` in trickyString. I have upvoted your answer. Thanks.